# Configuring Apache Virtual Hosts on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, macos-catalina

I setup Apache + PHP on Mac OS for development purposes and the localhost "site" works fine. When I try to setup a new Virtual Host ([from these instructions](https://jasonmccreary.me/articles/configure-apache-virtualhost-mac-os-x/)) my site (from virtual host) returns 403.

The folder structure for the virtual hosts is:

```
/Users/kipill/Documents/workspace/sandbox/htdocs
```

In my configuration, the `workspace` folder will contain all of my virtual hosts and the `sandbox` folder my first virtual host that I was trying to set up.

I set up `chmod 755` to every folder from lower level - `htdocs` up to `Documents`. I checked the permissions of every folder with `stat -f %A foldername` and this command on every folder and it returns 755, but my site still returns 403 forbidden. What else must I setup to achieve my goal?

Comment: Save yourself a headache and don’t attempt to muck around with system level Apache and PHP in macOS. Instead I highly recommend using [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) and then do your virtual host adjustments in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`. MAMP treats the Apache/PHP development environment as a standalone application that is 100% self contained. Safer to deal with than system stuff and it’s honestly easier to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved my files for virtual hosts to location /Users/kipill/webprojects and solve my issue.